# Join 2 layers based on overlapping features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge

I have two layers: (1) zipcodes (2) census tracts

I am analyzing a selection of 100 census tracts. Is there a way to process which census tracts are in each zipcodes based on their overlap?

i.e. for zip code 21223 there is census tracts 250203, 250204 250301 etc.

There are many census tracts (red border) in each zipcode (black border). 
[image]

But each census tract (purple with red border) could also be in many zipcodes (yellow layer). 
[image]

Is there a way to generate this zipcode-census tract list or join/create attribute tables based on the two layer's overlap? The zipcode layer has a column of 'zipcode' and the census tract has a column of 'census tract id,' but there is no mutual information between the two attribute tables.